# Highlighting Significant Comparison Rows in SPSS

Tags: formatting, output, spss, significance

I have SPSS output tables (see link) that I would like to modify so that rows with significant differences are highlighted (in light gray). Significant differences are indicated by the subscripts (a or b) being different within a row (1st row- no difference- non-significant, second row- difference-significant, etc).  I would also like the subscripts to disappear in the final version of the table. This must be done in SPSS to preserve the “look” I have chosen for the tables (or with some SPSS plug-in)! How could this be accomplished? Thank you!!

Here is an output table like the ones I am working with: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJCI1.png

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog item on this at the end of 2013.  You can find it here.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/ab16c38e-2f7b-4912-a47e-85682d124d32/entry/coloring_significance_in_spss_statistics_custom_tables_output?lang=en